# browsertime --- The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH

Tags: java, node.js, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Good night, i am trying to use the next https://github.com/sitespeedio/browsertime,  then i did the next

```
npm install browsertime -g
browsertime https://www.sitespeed.io/
```

When i executed the next command browsertime https://www.sitespeed.io/, but i am getting the next error

[image: Error]

[2022-03-30 18:47:29] INFO: Running tests using Chrome - 3 iteration(s)
[2022-03-30 18:47:29] INFO: chrome failed to start, trying 2 more time(s): The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.
[2022-03-30 18:47:29] INFO: chrome failed to start, trying 1 more time(s): The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.
[2022-03-30 18:47:29] INFO: chrome failed to start, trying 0 more time(s): The ChromeDriver could not be found on the current PATH. Please download the latest version of the ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and ensure it can be found on your PATH.

My chromedriver version is

> C:\Users\wilso>ChromeDriver Starting ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60
> (6a5d10861ce8de5fce22564658033b43cb7de047-refs/branch-heads/4896@{#875})
> on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed. Please see
> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for
> suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. ChromeDriver was started
> successfully.

Comment: What version of the chrome driver do you have in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: @FelixSchildmann my chrome driver version is ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60